# How to dynamically change filename while writing in a loop?

Tags: c

I would like to do something like this: In a loop, first iteration write some content into a file named file0.txt, second iteration file1.txt and so on, just increase the number.

```
FILE *img;
int k = 0;
while (true)
{
            // here we get some data into variable data

    file = fopen("file.txt", "wb");
    fwrite (data, 1, strlen(data) , file);
    fclose(file );

    k++;

            // here we check some condition so we can return from the loop
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
int k = 0;
while (true)
{
    char buffer[32]; // The filename buffer.
    // Put "file" then k then ".txt" in to filename.
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(char) * 32, "file%i.txt", k);

    // here we get some data into variable data

    file = fopen(buffer, "wb");
    fwrite (data, 1, strlen(data) , file);
    fclose(file );

    k++;

    // here we check some condition so we can return from the loop
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A different way to do it in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string someData = "this is some data that'll get written to each file";
    int k = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        // Formulate the filename
        std::ostringstream fn;
        fn << "file" << k << ".txt";

        // Open and write to the file
        std::ofstream out(fn.str().c_str(),std::ios_base::binary);
        out.write(&someData[0],someData.size());

        ++k;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FILE *img;
int k = 0;
while (true)
{
    // here we get some data into variable data
    char filename[64];
    sprintf (filename, "file%d.txt", k);

    file = fopen(filename, "wb");
    fwrite (data, 1, strlen(data) , file);
    fclose(file );
    k++;

            // here we check some condition so we can return from the loop
}
```

Answer (score 2):

so create the filename using sprintf:

```
char filename[16]; 
sprintf( filename, "file%d.txt", k );  
file = fopen( filename, "wb" ); ...
```

(although that is a C solution so the tag is not correct)

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this in the manner below. Note that unlike a few of the other examples, this will actually compile and function as intended by without any modification beside preprocessor includes. The solution below iterates fifty filenames.

```
int main(void)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 50; k++)
    {
        char title[8];
        sprintf(title, "%d.txt", k);
        FILE* img = fopen(title, "a");
        char* data = "Write this down";
        fwrite (data, 1, strlen(data) , img);
        fclose(img);
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean 51 names: 0 and 50 each count as one name (not sure which is the one you forgot to account for). You can see this quickly by noting that from 0 to 10 (< 11) there are actually 11 names.